# Aligning two equations on a selected pair of symbols

Tags: math-mode, equations

How can I center an equation according to `\Leftrightarrow`? I would like the second`\Leftrightarrow` to be below the first.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x = r \cos \varphi = 0 \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad \cos\varphi = 0,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y= 56 \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad \sin\alpha = ,
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't help but comment that if `\Leftrightarrow` is supposed to mean "if and only if", the statement in the first equatioin is incorrect: `r\cos\varphi=0` is true if either `\cos\varphi=0` *or* `r=0`.

Comment: `\Leftrightarrow` can be replaced with `\iff`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you

- replace the two `equation` enviroments with a single `align` environment, and
- insert `&` alignment points in front of the two `\Leftrightarrow` directives.

The `align` LaTeX environment is one of several tools the `amsmath` package provides for typesetting multi-line math constructs. It would be an excellent idea for you to familiarize yourself with the [user guide](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) of the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=r\cos\varphi=0 \qquad &\Leftrightarrow \qquad \cos\varphi=0 \\
y = 56           \qquad &\Leftrightarrow \qquad \sin\alpha=\dotsc
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank's to @Mico

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align} 
    x = r \cos \varphi = 0 \qquad &\Leftrightarrow \qquad \cos\varphi = 0, \\
    y= 56 \qquad &\Leftrightarrow \qquad \sin\alpha =0 , 
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```